# canvas jagged edges woes with lines/strokes

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm having a little problem with drawn lines on a canvas,

Basically I want the lines to be nice and soft and semi opaque however the canvas only seems to want to do this with last rendered line segment.

Have a look here, you will see that the last line segment drawn is nice and.. well how I want it) however as the animation plays, the lines drawn prior get all jaggy and nasty.

I've noticed that if i use closepath this doesn't happen however, because of the interval/animation i cant use this each render as the line goes all over the place:

http://jsfiddle.net/xSPuM/1/

anyone have any ideas on how to stop this happening, i'd be very grateful.

Thanks very much
A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange code! The animation is neat though the way of doing this seems a bit unique, so lets take a look.

First just to be completely clear, when you are making a path you can continue to stroke it over and over.

So if you have a path with three line segments A,B,C and you do:

A, stroke, B, stroke, C, stroke

You will get segment A stroked 3 times, B stroked 2 times and C stroked once.

This is essentially what you're doing here.

You can avoid that easily by stroking only once at the end of your path:

http://jsfiddle.net/xSPuM/5/

This stops the animation but illustrates what the problem is. You can fix the animation by clearing the screen. So with segments ABC we'd be doing:

A, clear, stroke, B, clear, stroke, C, clear, stroke

Then you'd get segment A stroked once, the screen is cleared and then segment A-B stroked once and the screen is cleared a final time so segment A-B-C gets stroked once. This is what you want.

The problem with this is that clearing the screen means clearing all your previously drawn shapes! See here:

http://jsfiddle.net/xSPuM/7/

There are a few ways to fix this:

1. Save the object currently being drawn on a temporary canvas (might be tricky)
2. Save the previously drawn state to a temporary canvas (less tricky)
3. Keep track of the three paths as if they were one path (easy peasy so I'll do it for you)

To do #3 all we gotta do is not call `beginPath` at the start of each new part. Instead we only call `beginPath` just once at the very start, and each new part is simply a `moveTo` operation!

http://jsfiddle.net/xSPuM/8/

That should be enough info to get you on the right track!

Comment: this is very cool, thanks for your help, however there seems to be quite a big reduction in speed by the time it gets to the last part. Any idea what might be causing this in your amends? the clearing and redrawing?

Comment: only reason I'm questioning such a prolific solution/answer is that there are about 5 other drawing objects I have to composite also so it's going to get pretty heavy...:-)

Comment: That might be. Taking out the console.log statements should help slightly: http://jsfiddle.net/xSPuM/11/

Comment: hah! fair enough, actually I've been reading this:http://simonsarris.com/blog/427-increasing-performance-by-caching-paths-on-canvas on your (pretty useful) blog and thought it might be applicable.

Comment: It's true, that may help, but *only* if you're not going to be actively animating the thing! One thing you can do for instance which I billed as #2 in my answer is cache the already-done paths to canvases (images really) precisely for the reasons in my blog. Drawing an image will always be faster than drawing 30 beziers over and over!